# Is there a name for the repulsive force or pressure quality of energy that is harnessed to do work?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, entropy, terminology

I read a book recently (The Information by James Gleick) that states energy is conserved. The author explained that the energy in gasoline used for driving still exists in the same amount although dispersed and changed to other forms such as heat, motion, sound and so on. So if energy is not doing the work because it is not being spent then what is doing the work? What is the name for the force (if that's what it is) that causes energy to disperse and change it's form, doing work in the process. I understand (I think) that entropy is another name for the quality of dispersed energy and or information, but I came away from the book wondering what is the name for the self repulsive quality of energy that we exploit to do work which causes energy to disperse and change and makes entropy increase?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The author explained that the energy in gasoline used for driving still exists in the same amount although dispersed and changed to other forms such as heat, motion, sound and so on. **So if energy is not doing the work because it is not being spent then what is doing the work?**

Physicists don't use the word work in the way you have used. A qualitative definition of work is that:

> **WORK**: It is the amount of energy gained /lossed by an object.

Mathematically this is said as $$W=\Delta E =\int \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf s$$.

> What is the name for the force (if that's what it is) that causes energy to disperse and change it's form, doing work in the process?

There are many types of forces that do work. Some examples are:

- Frictional force
- Gravitational force
- Muscular Force
- Electrostatic force

... and the list goes on.

Comment: Thanks, @The Last Airbender, I'm starting to see from your list. Say the car is electric and we are diving it up a hill. Electric energy is truly spent to create mechanical force which now stores gravitational energy. Driving back down spends gravitational energy to make mechanical force which generates electricity to put back in the battery. We could go back and forth forever if not for friction force from the moving car parts opposes the mechanical force creating heat energy which means less electrical energy for the battery.

Comment: So there is no repellent quality of energy that creates entropy. Only undesired forces. Furthermore, energy is fully spent when making other forms of energy. So in that sense it really isn't conserved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John If you had any question about such topics you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). Though one thing that I want to state is that energy is always conserved ( You might have heard **Energy can neither be created nor be destroyed.**)